# keycloak HTTP 401 Unauthorized?

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I am using keycloak as IAM tool for registration and authentication,
I have set every thing , realm, client, admin role with realm-management composite roles, in order to be able register and authenticat, every thing is working fine but, I have an api where I am trying to get information about the user:

```
public UserRepresentation getUserInfo(String id) {

        UserRepresentation res = null;
        try {
            res = getRealmResource().users().get(id).toRepresentation();
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            
            e.printStackTrace();
            
            throw e;
        }
        return res;
    }
```

this request espicially and other request in general, sometimes return

> 'javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized'

and the stackTrace is like below:

> **************** CATCHING ERROR ****************** javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized  at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.handleErrorStatus(ClientInvocation.java:266)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.extractResult(ClientInvocation.java:240)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.extractors.BodyEntityExtractor.extractEntity(BodyEntityExtractor.java:64)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invokeSync(ClientInvoker.java:154)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientInvoker.invoke(ClientInvoker.java:115)
> at
> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.proxy.ClientProxy.invoke(ClientProxy.java:76)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy215.toRepresentation(Unknown Source)     at
> ava.io.authentication_manager.services.KeycloakService.getUserInfo(KeycloakService.java:264)
> at
> ava.io.authentication_manager.services.KeycloakService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$79325096.invoke()
> at
> org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.invokeMethod(CglibAopProxy.java:386)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.access$000(CglibAopProxy.java:85)
> at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:704)
> at
> ava.io.authentication_manager.services.KeycloakService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e4663f6.getUserInfo()
> at
> ava.io.authentication_manager.controllers.AuthController.getUserInfo(AuthController.java:173)
> at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown
> Source)   at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)     at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)     at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:121)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:105)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter.java:121)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)
> at
> org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:156)
> at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 2023-08-08
> 12:24:56.639 ERROR 1 --- [nio-7777-exec-8]
> a.i.a.services.KeycloakService           :
> **************** END OF ERROR STACKTRACE ******************

I am pretty sure that I gave the right access to the client and the admin user and the right roles, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
this is the code for getting the realm resource:

```
@Bean
    public Keycloak getInstance() {
        return KeycloakBuilder.builder()
                .serverUrl(serverUrl + "/auth")
                .realm(realm)
                .grantType(OAuth2Constants.PASSWORD)
                .clientId(resource)
                .clientSecret(credentials.getSecret())
                .username(userName)
                .password(password)
                .resteasyClient(new ResteasyClientBuilderImpl().connectionPoolSize(resteasy_pool_size).build())
                .build();


    }

    public RealmResource getRealmResource() {
            return keycloak.realm(keyCloakConfig.getRealm());
        }
```

the "username password ...." is taking from application.yml
and the idea that this exception is some thing happening arbitrary, not for every request I do not know if some thing related to the keycloak client version here is the one I use:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
            <version>21.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

EDIT2:
I found what causing the issue but still not fixed,
the admin user that I am using is authenticated before try to get the other resource , so what happining that some times the session of that admin user is deleted, I not so sure if it is deleted by external factor or due to session expiration , with that been said I have configured the session ttl and idle for long time, and still monitoring, any suggistion?

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve your Keycloak admin client usage issue, but, if your API is configured as a resource server with JWT decoder, a much more efficient way to expose current user attributes is reflecting access token claims (this saves calls to Keycloak):

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/me")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    public Map<String, Object> getMe(JwtAuthenticationToken auth) {
        return auth.getTokenAttributes();
    }
}
```

You could use a path matcher in the security configuration instead of method security as done here, but don't forget to check for a valid authentication or you might have an `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` in the security context (instead of the `JwtAuthenticationToken` as expected by the code above).

If you prefer an empty map rather than a 401 for anonymous requests, you could do this instead:

```java
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/me")
    public Map<String, Object> getMe(Authentication auth) {
        if (auth instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwt) {
            return jwt.getTokenAttributes();
        }
        return Map.of();
    }
}
```